# Space in number format in Angular

Tags: angular

The value of a number is not displayed as I want.

For example, the number value is displayed like this currently `380000.00` and I want to display `380 000.00`

How to create this space?

*pipe*

```
export class NumNoCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  isNotComma(charecter: string): boolean {
    return charecter !== ','
  }

  transform(value: string | null): string {
    return [...value!].filter(this.isNotComma).join("");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use an angular expression

```
const spaces = price => String(price)
  .replace(
    /(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,
    ' '
  );

for (let i = 1; i < 1e10; i *= 10) {
  console.log(spaces(i));
}
```